# Intersection Point in SVG/GSAP Game

Tags: jquery, svg, gsap

I have set-up a codepen for reference, the problem is that I need to find the intersection point when the arrow and the stone collide (Everything is SVG), and after collision have to hide both of them, the stone moves when we click the rotator of the Trebuchet, and arrow should start on its own after the page loads.

The arrow should follow the light blue color path, and stone follows the grey thin line path. I have broken my head like crazy any suggestion will be of great help. The link of codepen is : - [Click Here to view Codepen](https://codepen.io/abhilash27/pen/EyRWwg)

```
$("#wheel-moving").click(function () {

        $('#rope').css('display','none');
        TweenMax.to(".rotateFireButton", .85, {x:25, y:140, rotation:180, transformOrigin:"50% 50%", ease: Power1.easeIn} )

        TweenMax.fromTo(".throwMachineLow", .2  , {x:2 , y:79.1 }, {x:2, y:79.1, delay:.3, rotation:57, transformOrigin:"84% 0%", ease: Power1.easeIn} )
        TweenMax.fromTo("#heavy-block", .2  , {x:182.7 , y:71.5 }, {x:160, y:100, delay:.3, transformOrigin:"84% 0%", ease: Power1.easeIn} )
        TweenMax.to(".throwMachineLow", .5  , {x:2, y:79.1, delay:.95, rotation:0, transformOrigin:"84% 0%", ease: Power1.easeIn} )
        TweenMax.to("#heavy-block", .5  , {x:182.7 , y:71.5, delay:.95, transformOrigin:"84% 0%", ease: Power1.easeIn} )
        TweenMax.to(".rotateFireButton", .85, {x:25, y:140, delay:.95, rotation:-180, transformOrigin:"50% 50%", ease: Power1.easeIn} )
        setTimeout( function(){ 
            $('#rope').css('display','initial');

        }  , 1500 );
        var stonePath = MorphSVGPlugin.pathDataToBezier("#stoneRunner",{align:"#stone",offsetX:-310,offsetY:-240});

        TweenMax.to(
            $("#stone"), 3,
            {
                delay:.27, 
                autoAlpha: 1,
                visibility:'visible',
                bezier: {values:stonePath, type:"cubic"},
                transformOrigin:"100% 100%"
            });
        fire();
    });

function fire(){
        $('#wheel-moving').css('pointer-events','none');    
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#wheel-moving').css('pointer-events','auto');
        }, 2000);
    }
```

Comment: It's not a simple task to do this mathematically. Google intersection of bezier curves. But you can get a good enough approximation (for a game) by breaking down your bezier curves into straight line segments and doing the much simpler task of determining which of those line segments intersect with each other.

Comment: I have made this entire svg in sketch and then incorporated it in HTML, so I was getting a range of co-ordinates using the ruler but it just fails to detect the collision, so not able to figure out where exactly I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution, It is easy to make both the arrow and the stone to follow the path using GSAP, after that to find the intersection point, first find the length of the path can get it in the bottom of this link https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/ then use this value in stroke-dashoffset and using hit-n-trial you can find the values at which they intersect just change the values from 0 to pathLength you will get the idea, it is actually tricky but it was worth the time! I'll update the codepen as well.